# Tutorials for Flurry Analytics in Android ?

Tags: android, flurry

I am new to **Flurry Analytics** in Android, where can I find basic tutorials to work on it?

Comment: http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2010/01/discovering-flurry.html
this link will be help full for you.... :)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually really simple.

1 - Head to flurry.com and register for your app, which will generate a unique tracking code.

2 - Download and add the FlurryAgent jar to your project libraries. If you're using Eclipse, right-click your project folder, select properties, select Java Build Path, and choose Add External JARs...

3 - Add android.permission.INTERNET to your AndroidManifest.xml.

4 - Add a call to the Flurry agent from the onStart() and onStop methods of your activities.

Note: replace the ID below with your unique tracking code.

```
public void onStart()
{
   super.onStart();
   FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "9GKQD4EBX123FEP6874H");
   // your code
}

public void onStop()
{
   super.onStop();
   FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
   // your code
}
```

That's It !

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/#get-started

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods (during a session only) to report additional data:

```
FlurryAgent.logEvent(String eventId)
FlurryAgent.logEvent(String eventId, boolean timed)
FlurryAgent.logEvent(String eventId, Map<String, String> parameters)
FlurryAgent.logEvent(String eventId, Map<String, String> parameters, boolean        timed)
```

Tutorials :

http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/01/setting-up-analytics-for-your-android-app/

http://abibrothers.blogspot.in/2012/10/flurry-analytics.html